# Could anyone point me in the right direct to fix this?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I am receiving the error

Error #2044: Unhandled SQLErrorEvent:. errorID=3115, operation=execute , message=Error #3115: SQL Error. , details=near 'TEXT': syntax error

I am trying to learn programming, so I am following a video tutorial exactly. I have spent the past 3 hours looking for this syntax error and am trying to stay on course with the training.  Could anyone please point me in the correct direction "Sadly the paid video course does not offer HELP :( "  to solve this issue?  It would also be nice to know if i can create the database in its own view and have other views write to it and pull data from it I don't know if the training will touch on this or not but would like to know where i can learn how to do this in a flex environment.

```
                                                                     the error below
            statement.text = "INSERT INTO archive (variable TEXT, variable TEXT) VALUES ('"+variable+"','"+variable+"')";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the beginning of your SQL statement to this:

```
INSERT INTO archive (title, journal) VALUES
```

You shouldn't include the data type in your insert statement.

Comment: Thank you so much!  IT removed the error I appreciate it!   I am removing the Code from this question other then the error portion